# Quickblox Javascript SDK + Angular + webRTC - Firefox Error: SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, webrtc, quickblox

Quickblox Media Recorder is showing this error when I insert the remote stream into:

```
Error: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.  quickblox.min.js:88148:15
    [526]</Utils.safeCallbackCall https://teledev.caduceususa.com/js/quickblox.min.js:88148:15
    [517]</WebRTCSession.prototype._onRemoteStreamListener https://teledev.caduceususa.com/js/quickblox.min.js:86831:5
    [513]</RTCPeerConnection.prototype.onAddRemoteStreamCallback https://teledev.caduceususa.com/js/quickblox.min.js:85276:5

QBMediaRecorder is not created or has an invalid state.
```

Here is the code:

```
 QB.webrtc.onRemoteStreamListener = function(session, userID, remoteStream) {
            $scope.session.attachMediaStream('remoteVideoEl', remoteStream);
        $scope.recorder.start(remoteStream);
        $scope.$apply();
};
```

Is there a different way to make firefox behave when recording a remote stream?

Comment: can you connect quickblox.js (not min version) and post what's in this line quickblox.min.js:88148:15

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue on bug tracker of FF https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1212237

Also, I recommend making a record on yourself side cause you can have the bad connection or something else. In this case, you will have an error and record will be broken possible.

One more thing, are you using this recorder https://github.com/QuickBlox/javascript-media-recorder ?